# Convert number letters to counter compatible numbers? (datatool, newcounter)

Tags: counters, datatool

I read in some data from a CSV file with `datatool` like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
STUFF,NUMBER
"twentyfour",24
"thirtyone",31
"blank",
"minusseven",-7
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{test.csv}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{examplecounter}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
Stuff & Number \\
\hline

\DTLforeach*{data}{%
    \TestStuff=STUFF,%assignments
    \TestNumber=NUMBER% really just a number like 1, 2, 3...
}{%
    \setcounter{examplecounter}{\TestNumber} % this does not work
    \\
    \TestStuff & \arabic{examplecounter}
}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I need to assign the imported number to a counter for some calculations. Basically I need something like `\arabic{}` in reverse.

I must use `\DTLloaddb{}` and can't use `\DTLloadrawdb{}`, because the same csv file contains some well-printed text with LaTeX format instructions like `\emph{}`. (I don't know it that *would* help...)

Comment: Don't use `\number=NUMBER`, since `\number` is a primitive. Let's assume you use `\NUMBER`, then you need `\setcounter{examplecounter}{\NUMBER}`. You currently have `\newcounter`...

Comment: `\number` was just for the mwe. In reality I of course use some more explaining name. And I have to admit that I currently try `\setcounter` instead of `\newcounter`. And it does not work.

Comment: I found the error. some of the data was empty and no number... should/can I delete this question?

Comment: I updated your minimal example to actually replicate the behaviour.

Comment: So it's not the same question I initialy asked, but it suits my problem better and helped. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number conversions from a CSV work as expected, allowing you to execute

```
\setcounter{<cntr>}{<cmd>}
```

where `<cmd>`. However, this may be problematic if `<cmd>` turns out to be blank (or null). Luckily [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) provides a conditional for checking this in the form

```
\DTLifnullorempty{<cmd>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
STUFF,NUMBER
"twentyfour",24
"thirtyone",31
"blank",
"minusseven",-7
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{test.csv}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{examplecounter}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  Stuff & Number \\
  \hline
  \DTLforeach*{data}{%
      \TestStuff=STUFF,%assignments
      \TestNumber=NUMBER% really just a number like 1, 2, 3...
  }{%
      \DTLifnullorempty{\TestNumber}{}{\setcounter{examplecounter}{\TestNumber}} % this does not work
      \\
      \TestStuff & \TestNumber
  }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```